# How to solve the Sort and Combine problem

Tags: python

I am attempting to combine four lists of one row and two columns, such as `line_parts=[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]]`, to create a list of one row and five columns, such as `all_lines=[[5, 2, 1, 2, 0]]`.
However, the list of four 1-line 2-column lists is written as `line_parts=[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]]`, but I would like to make it a 1-line 5-column list even if it is `[[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [5, 2]]`, `[[2, 1], [1, 2], [5, 2], [2, 0]]`, `[[1, 2], [5, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1]]`, etc.

Currently, I am able to create a one-row, five-column list for `[[5, 2, 1, 2, 0]]` from `line_parts=[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]]`.

```
line_parts=[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]]

lines = []
for i,j in line_parts:
    if i == 5:
        path = [ int(i), j ]
        line_parts.remove(line_parts[line_parts.index([i,j])])
        while len(path) != len(line_parts) + 2:
            if path[-1] == 0:
                del path[-1]
                line_parts.insert(len(line_parts),line_parts[0])
                line_parts.remove(line_parts[0])
            else:
                line_parts.insert(len(line_parts),line_parts[0])
                line_parts.remove(line_parts[0])
                while path[-1] != 0:
                    line_parts.insert(len(line_parts),line_parts[0])
                    line_parts.remove(line_parts[0])
                    for m, n in line_parts:
                        if m == path[-1]:
                            path.append(n)
                            break
        lines.append(path)
all_lines=lines

print("all_lines:",all_lines)
```

The result of running the above program is as follows

```
all_lines: [[5, 2, 1, 2, 0]]
```

However, when I change `line_parts=[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]]` to `line_parts=[[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [5, 2]]`, an infinite loop occurs and I don't get a 1-line, 5-column list like `[[5, 2, 1, 2, 0]]`.
I have tried to improve it, but it keeps repeating over and over again that one pattern outputs a one-line, five-column list like [[5, 2, 1, 2, 0]], but another pattern does not work.

Can you please give me some hints or suggestions on how to improve the program so that I can get a one-line, five-column list in all cases, not just `[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]]`, but `[[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [5, 2]]`, `[[2, 1], [1, 2], [5, 2], [2, 0]]`, `[[1, 2], [5, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1]]`, etc.?

Thank you in advance.

【Supplementary Explanation】

Here is the logic.
I'm sorry, but I've made it less concise by including the looping process.

[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]] can be represented in alphabetical form as [[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]].
In the background of this problem, we want to move from a to d at a time, and we can think of b and c as the transit points between a and d.

1. Among the lists contained in `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]`, if there is a list with a at `index 0`, define path based on the elements at `index 0` and `index 1` of that list. (When looking for a list with a at `index 0`, start from the top of the list.)
   ⇒The result is `path=[a,b]`.
2. Delete elements `[a, b]` from the list `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]`.
   ⇒`[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]` becomes `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b]]`.
3. The number of elements in path is not equal to the number of lists in `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b]]` plus `2`, so the (first) while loop is continued.
   ⇒The number of elements in path is `3`, and the latter is `5`, so they are not equal.
4. Since the end of `path=[a,b]` is not `d`, the element with `index 0` in `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b]]` is moved to the end of the list, and the element with `index 0` is removed from the list.
   ⇒The result is `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b]]` to `[[b, d], [c, b],[b, c]]`.
5. The path does not end in `d`, so the (second) while loop is continued.
6. Move the element with `index 0` in `[[b, d], [c, b],[b, c]]` to the end of the list, and delete (the element with `index 0`) from the list.
   ⇒The result is `[[b, d], [c, b],[b, c]]` to `[[c, b],[b, c],[b, d]]`.
7. Among the lists enclosed in `[[c, b],[b, c],[b, d]]`, if there is a list with `b` (the element at the end of `path=[a,b]`) at `index 0`, add the element at `index 1` of that list to the end of path.  (When looking for a list with `d`, start from the top of the list.)
   ⇒The result is `path=[a,b,c]`.
8. Since the end of path is not `d`, continue the (second) while loop.
9. Move the element with `index 0` in `[[c, b],[b, c],[b, d]]` to the end of the list, and delete the element with `index 0` from the list.
   ⇒The result is `[[c, b],[b, c],[b, d]]` to `[[b, c],[b, d],[c, b]]`.
10. Among the lists contained in `[[b, c],[b, d],[c, b]]`, if there is a list with `c` at `index 0` (the element at the end of `path=[a,b,c]`), add the element at `index 1` of that list to the end of path. (When looking for `a` list with `c`, start from the top of the list.)
    ⇒The result is `path=[a,b,c,b]`.
11. Since the end of path is not `d`, the (second) while loop is continued.
12. The element with `index 0` in `[[b, c],[b, d],[c, b]]` is moved to the end of the list, and (the element with index 0) is deleted from the list.
    ⇒The result is `[[b, c],[b, d],[c, b]]` to `[[b, d],[c, b],[b, c]]`.
13. Among the lists contained in `[[b, d],[c, b],[b, c]]`, if there is a list with `b` (the last element of `path=[a,b,c,b]`) at `index 0`, add the element at `index 1` of that list to the end of path.  (When looking for a list with `b`, start from the top of the list.)
    ⇒The result is `path=[a,b,c,b,d]`.
14. Exit from the (second) while loop because the end of path is `d`.
15. The number of elements of path and the number of lists contained in `[[b, d],[c, b],[b, c]]` plus `2` are equal, so we exit the (first) while loop.
    ⇒The number of elements in path is `5`, and the latter is also equal to `5`.
16. Add path to lines.
    ⇒The result is `lines=[[a,b,c,b,d]]`.
17. From `all_lines=lines`, we get `all_lines=[[a,b,c,b,d]]`.

This concludes the algorithm.

Thank you very much for reading to the end.
I would be very grateful for your comments.
If there is anything that needs to be added, please let me know.

Comment: Can you explain (simply) the logic to go from `[[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 2], [5, 2]]` to `[[5, 2, 1, 2, 0]]`, what if the input is `[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], [g, h]]`?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.

First of all, it is not possible to solve this problem if `a≠b≠c≠d≠e≠f≠g≠h`, so I am afraid I will have to add the necessary conditions on my end. This is because in this problem, duplicate elements at `index 1` and `index 0`, such as `[a, b]`, `[b, c]`, are combined to form `[a, c]`.

As for the logic of the main topic, I'm very sorry, but it's too long, so I'll put it in the body of the message as an edit instead of in the reply chat.

Comment: If your array is equivalent to `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]`, why not just using positions to get the final output instead of your complex algorithm?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

I think you are right, mozway.
I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but I've been thinking about an algorithm that uses location, and this is the result.
I have only been studying Python and algorithms for a short time, so I don't have much experience.
If you have any ideas for less complicated algorithms, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Well, the real question is what does this array represent? Why do you want to reshape? There are indeed easy ways to do it is the position is fixed

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I was surprised to learn that there is an easy way to fix it.
I felt hopeful because I had tried and failed many times.

Comment: As for your question (`Why do you want to reshape?`), you are referring to the process of "If there is a list that is contained in a list and has the element at the end of path at `index 0`, then add the element at `index 1` of that list to the end of path "Do you mean the process of (This is the process described in 7), 10), and 13) of the algorithm.)

Comment: This was introduced to shuffle the elements of the list and prevent the wrong solution from being output.

For example, if `path=[a, b]` and the list is in the order of `[[b, d], [b, c], [c, b]]`, then `d`, the last element of `[b, d]`, the element at `index 0` of the list, will be added to path. Then, `path=[a, b, d]` without going through `c` will be completed. This is a wrong solution because it does not go through all of a to d as in `path=[a, b, c, b, d]`.

Therefore, I thought a shuffle function was necessary to replace the elements in the list.

Comment: you have defined what you think is the good algorithm in 14 or so steps. but it doesn't work, that's why you're here. and it's waaaaay too long. i won't read it. what do you want to achieve? in simple words and just a few ones. because you say you want to go from a to d but you do `[a, b, c, b, d]` what is the LOGIC of that? why `[a, b, a, b, d]` is not a good answer? explain that with your own words. you have provided some possible inputs, what would be your expected result for those?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I am asking this question because it does not work as you say.

What I would like to achieve is that for all combinations of lists with different partial root positions (e.g. `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]`, `[[b, c], [a, b], [c, b], [b, d]]`, `[[c, b], [b, c], [a, b], [b, d]]`, etc.) I want to create an algorithm such that the result of solving the problem in any pattern is `[a, b, c, b, d]`.

Comment: As a premise, I am considering the problem of finding a route that starts at a, always goes through b and d, and arrives at d. In solving this problem, the lists `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]` represent partial routes between points. By combining these partial routes, the route from a to d can be derived.
The combination method requires that `index 1` in the preceding list is equal to `index 0` in the following list. For example, given a partial root of `[[a, b],[b, c]]`, it can be made into `[a, b, c]` by stacking the duplicate elements with `index 1` and `index 0`.

Comment: The reason why `[a, b, a, b, d]` is a wrong answer is that `[b, a]` is not among the candidates for the partial root. (Another reason why `[a, b, a, b, d]` is incorrect is that it is not included in the route even though it should go through `c`.)

Comment: If `[a, b, a, b, d]` is the correct answer, then there will be `[[a, b], [b, a], [a, b], [b, d]]` as one pattern of partial root combinations. You can see that this differs from the originally given list of partial roots `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]` in terms of the elements stored in the four-column list (rather than the position of the four-column list). Therefore, `[a, b, a, b, d]` will not be created, and is not the correct answer.
If you need additional explanation, I will do so.

Comment: `I would like to correct my comment four comments above, as it was not properly expressed in English.`
What I want to achieve is to create an algorithm such that the result of solving the problem is `[a, b, c, b, d]` for all 24 patterns in the list of partial roots. The patterns in the list of partial roots are, for example, `[[b, c], [b, d], [c, b], [a, b]]`, `[[b, c], [a, b], [c, b], [b, d]]`, and `[[c, b], [b, c], [a, b], [b, d]]`.

Comment: In the second comment from the top, I wrote: "Given the partial root `[[a, b],[b, c]]`, the overlapping elements of `index 1` and `index 0` can be superimposed to form `[[a, c]]`" 
I wrote that, but it was not correct. 
I’m very sorry for that. 
The correct answer is: Given the partial root `[[a, b],[b, c]]`, the overlapping elements of `index 1` and `index 0` can be superimposed to form `[[a, b, c]]`.

Comment: `for all 24 patterns in the list of partial roots` your pairs are fixed, and 24 is the permutations of these. so in your first example `[5,2,0]` is a solution but you want only solutions of length 5. am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you said.
No matter which list of 24 patterns you enter into the program, it needs to output a solution of length 5.
I'm sorry for my poor explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a disclaimer, i'm really not good at every subject covered by your question: graphs, algorithmics and recursion. but nobody answered and it was a good exercise

there are two problems to consider here: the specific problem implied by your examples (5 nodes 4 edges, i think the words are right?), and how to solve a more general problem (i think that's what your code tries to do).

solving the "24" is somewhat easy: by definition you already know 4 of the five nodes. you just have to find the one in the middle

```
def get_simple_path(lst):
    # flatten the list to make it easier to find max/min
    flat=[y for x in lst for y in x]
    result=[0]*5
    
    # first two and last two are found easily:
    # the max pair
    a=max(flat)
    result[0]=a
    for pair in lst:
        if pair[0]==a:
            result[1]=pair[1]
            lst.remove(pair)
    
    # the min pair
    d=min(flat)
    result[-1]=d
    for pair in lst:
        if pair[1]==d:
            result[-2]=pair[0]
            lst.remove(pair)
    
    # we're left with only two lists [ab, ba] or [ba, ab]
    # if a matches result[1], then result[2] is b, else it's a
    if result[1]==lst[0][0]:
        result[2]=lst[0][1]
    else:
        result[2]=lst[0][0]
    return result
```

it works with the 24 permutations and doesn't need any while loop

now for a more generalized solution we need recursion (at least i do). your version doesn't work because when it fails it cannot restore the state where it could still work (backtracking?).

```
def get_path(lst, left_val, res=[]):
    pairs=[]
    for i, pair in enumerate(lst):
        if pair[0]==left_val:
            pairs.append(pair)
    if pairs:
        for pair in pairs:
            lst2=lst.copy()
            lst2.remove(pair)
            res2=res.copy()
            res2.append(pair[0])
            if z:=get_path(lst2, pair[1], res2):
                return z
    elif not pairs and lst==[]:
        res.append(left_val)
        return res
```

to init the recursion, `left_val` is the max value of your list

if i try with `[[5, 8], [1, 6], [6, 7], [8, 0], [7, 3], [4, 1], [10, 6], [3, 4], [6, 5]]` and its 362880 permutations i always get `[10, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 8, 0]`

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time out of your busy schedule to reply.

Thank you very much for creating and explaining the program and my inadequacies.
As you said, I was having a hard time expressing the so-called backtracking in the program.

Also, although I posted a simple example in the question form, I was actually thinking of solving a problem that extends the example (with more nodes and edges), as diggusbickus guessed.
So, thank you very much for the "how to solve a more general problem".

Comment: I have checked the program logic and algorithm for both patterns. (I also checked the behavior of the program, and it produced the results I wanted, just like the answer form.)
I was very surprised that I could express backtracking without using while, because I could not have come up with such a program by myself due to my limited knowledge, and I learned a lot. I will make use of what I have learned in the future.

Comment: I apologize for making you spend more time and effort than necessary for my poor explanation.
I would also like to thank you for taking the time out of your busy schedule to consult with me.

Comment: i learned a lot too, thanks to you